# How to change Notepad++ syntax highlighting on typescript template string

Tags: typescript, notepad++, syntax-highlighting, template-strings

While using Notepad++ to write a template string in Typescript, when I have focus on the template string, the string foreground turns to white which contrasts badly with the background color, I checked Notepad++ style configurator in the settings tab, I did not see any option to change the foreground color of the template string when it has focus at all.

When the template string does not have focus, it looks nice

---

[image]

---

When it has focus, I can barely see the string

---

[image]

How do I change that?

Comment: Does [this help](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11366/javascript-back-tick-quoted-strings-bad-color/6)?

Comment: That was just perfect, didn't know it was called stringraw in notepad++. Sincerely appreciate it @KenY-N

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++ now support TypeScript:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Editor-Support#notepad

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to settings -> Style Configurator.

2) Select **Language**: JavaScript and **Style**: STRINGRAW.

3) Change Background colour to white and foreground to a dark color.

If desired you can also enable or disable current line highlighting by going to Settings -> Preferences -> Editing -> Enable current line highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, So I renamed this file:

```
%appdata%\Notepad++\stylers.xml
```

After closing and re opening the np++, the problem was fixed.